# Open a Xml table in Excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I checked several tutorials, and similar questions but I can't resolve my problem.

I can do what I need, but this option opens a new workbook and then copies everything to the macros.xlsm sheet Lote.

How can I do this directly on the Excel workbook that has the macro.

```vb
Sub Import1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim TheFile As String
Dim instance As XPath
Dim Map As XmlMap
Dim XPath As String
Dim Book As String
Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject

Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

clipboard.SetText ""
clipboard.PutInClipboard

ChDir "C:\rwindows"

TheFile = Application _
.GetOpenFilename("XML Files (*.xml), *.xml", , "Import XML", , False)

Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=TheFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)

With ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("evs_rpb_Mapa")
    .ShowImportExportValidationErrors = False
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .PreserveColumnFilter = True
    .PreserveNumberFormatting = True
    .AppendOnImport = True
End With

fileToOpen = Application _
.GetOpenFilename("XML Files (*.xml), *.xml", , "Import XML", , True)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If IsArray(fileToOpen) Then
    For Each fil In fileToOpen
        ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("evs_rpb_Mapa").Import URL:=fil
    Next fil
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

Book = ActiveWindow.Caption
'Windows("Livro1").Activate
Windows(Book).Activate
Columns("A:AL").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Macros.xlsm").Activate
Columns("A:AL").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows(Book).Activate
ActiveWindow.Close
Columns("A:AL").Select

Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

clipboard.SetText ""
clipboard.PutInClipboard

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This will get you acquainted with the ways to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post sample XML to show how you can build XmlMap and iteratively append XML data to it.

Comment: I can't add the xml file, i didn't have permission of the company. I edit the code, and now I just need to do this in the macros.xlsm and not in another workbook and then copy all information

Answer (score 0):

Consider selecting folder of XML files from a folder picker dialog and then iteratively import XMLs into single map using a loop:

```vb
Sub XMLImport()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim folderToOpen As Variant, fil As Variant
    Dim folderDialog As FileDialog

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' RETRIEVE XML FOLDER
    Set folderDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With folderDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            folderToOpen = folderDialog.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            MsgBox "No folder selected.", vbExclamation, "NO FOLDER"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    ' SET  XML MAP SETTINGS
    ChDir "C:\rwindows"
    With ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("evs_rpb_Mapa")
        .ShowImportExportValidationErrors = False
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .PreserveColumnFilter = True
        .PreserveNumberFormatting = True
        .AppendOnImport = True
    End With

    ' ITERATE THROUGH ALL XMLS IN FOLDER
    fil = Dir(folderToOpen)
    Do While Len(fil) > 0
        If Right(fil, 3) = "xml" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("evs_rpb_Mapa").Import URL:=folderToOpen & fil
        End If
        fil = Dir
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
   MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
   Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. I tested and did not do anything.

Comment: Really? Did you run the macro? No file dialog launched to pick folder? Remarkable! Works great on my end with a workbook having a pre-existing XML map.

Comment: Yes, I copy all and when I run the Macro I have error in this line: On Error GoTo ErrHandle. If I remove this line I have a menu to select the xmls but Im not able to see them.

Comment: And I receive this error: Range.Xpath.SetValue. Im trying in excel 2016, Isn't that the problem? Best regards

Comment: Whoops! Error handle was cut off. I added it at end. As mentioned, the dialog is a **folder** picker, not file picker where you select directory were 100 xmls reside. And you need to post some XML data, XSD that builds map, screenshot to reproduce issue. Be sure you have a pre-existing XmlMap in current workbook and imported XMLs align to it.